# Float links on top-right and top-left corners of an image

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside a div. I want two links to float over the image, one on top-left and other top-right of the image. I did this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div style="float:left"><a href="#">like</a></div>
  <div style="float:right"><a href="#">share</a></div>
  <img src="images/activity-image.jpg" />
</div>
```

Floating divs push the image down. But, I want them to appear upon the image. It should look as if the like and share links are on the top-left and top-right corners of the image and not above the image. Hope I got the explanation clear.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this, but adjust the CSS positioning of the h2 element equivalent to suit your needs: http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

Comment: Worked perfect! I had landed earlier on this page from Google, but couldn't get it worked then. Now, it works for me. Thanks for pointing me all again back there. Cheers!

You should have added this as an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: No problem, and answer added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this, but adjust the CSS positioning of the h2 element equivalent to suit your needs: css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image

Comment: Worked perfect for my case. Thanks! However, @imbondbaby solution also works, but for a background image. So, both RSid and imbondbaby gave the answer right. Since answer by RSid fits my case, I mark this as accepted. Thanks all for your quick help :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `absolute` position within a `relative` positioned element and use `top`, `bottom`, `right` and `left` properties to position the text.

Try this:

```css
.top{
    top: 0;
}
.left{
    left: 0;
}
.right{
    right: 0;
}
.img{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: url("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png") no-repeat;
}
.img span{
    position: absolute;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
    <span class="top left">text</span>
    <span class="top right">text</span>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hxvL5nns/2/)**

Comment: Great! This also works like a charm. But, I want some styling to the image and so do not want the image to be used as background. However, this is a good way to have floating divs over a background image. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}
img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
.top_right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 8px;
}
.top_left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class = "top_right"><a href="#">like</a></div>
    <div class= "top_left"><a href="#">share</a></div>
    <img src="http://thevisualcommunicationguy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Starbucks-Logo-051711.gif" />
</div>
```

*PS* - This is with regard to your code. There could be other techniques as well.

[JS Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/lojafi/1/edit)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code works the way I want. Can you please let me know about the 'better ways' you mentioned??

Answer (score 0):

Have you set CSS positioning? Setting the image **`position: fixed`** may hold the image in place while you float the divs.

Comment: Adding position: fixed to the image makes it fixed on the screen. But, I want it to be fixed to the div. Also, the image gets pushed off the text instead having the text float on image.